# editorfor picks string template instead of double

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I'm having some issues with a view model in my project that contains an number of doubles in them

ie.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public double Left { get; set; }
    public double Right { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Bottom { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have

```
@Html.EditorForModel
```

If there is no other custom templates in my project this renders correctly and I get a textbox with a double on in it.

As soon as I put a string template in View/Shared/EditorTemplate and put anything inside of it whatever is in that template gets rendered instead of the double template.

I would have thought that even though I have overriden the string template the order for selecting templates would remain the same, and the double template would be choosen as it was originally before the string template existed.

The string template consisted of only (no @model )

```
<h2>String</h2>
```

Am I missing something here, why is the string template choosen here?

I've determined I can put a double template in the views shared folder and it will render that instead but it seems like I shouldn't have to do that.

**EDIT:**

As per Darin's answer I created my own double editortemplate based on the decimal template.

```
@using System.Globalization
@functions {

    private object FormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model)
            {
                return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:0.00}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
            }
            return ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;
        }
    }

}

@Html.TextBox("", FormattedValue, new {@class = "text-box single-line"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something here, why is the string template choosen here?

In both cases it's the String template being chosen. There's no default template for the double type. Here's how the default string template looks like:

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    new { @class = "text-box single-line" }
)
```

> I've determined I can put a double template in the views shared folder
>   and it will render that instead but it seems like I shouldn't have to
>   do that.

Well, if you are not satisfied with the default template for the double type (which is `string.cshtml`) you could always write a custom template for it.

Comment: You beat me to it! I assumed there was a built in template, its a bit hard to tell that there isnt, apart from this behaviour!

Comment: do you think theres a reason they didnt provide a double template?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a particular reason. Probably it's not needed. It's more common to use decimal for things like currencies and stuff. So they provided a template for the Decimal type.